# Proof regarding differentiability of $f$ and $g$

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone give me feedback regarding whether or not I'm on the right track for this proof? Thanks in advance!

> Suppose that $ f,g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are each
>   differentiable and that:  
>  
> $\forall$ $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$
>   $f'=g$. 
> $\forall$ $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ $g'=-f$. 
> $f(0)=0$.
>   
> $g(0)=1$. 
>  
> Show that $\forall$ $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$
>   $f^{2}+g^{2}=1$.

This is what I was thinking:
We know $ f,g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are each
differentiable. Consequently by a theorem in the book, the product $fg$ is differentiable. More specifically, $(fg)'=f'g+g'f$. Since $f'=g$ $\forall$ $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g'=-f$ $\forall$ $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $(fg)'=g^{2}-f^{2}$. 
And now here lies my problem. I was trying to come up with different ways that sums or products would give me $g^{2}+f^{2}$ and then I could use the final two conditions. But haven't been able to do so. Am I on the right track? Or am I not making any sense?

Comment: I don't think that track will work. Hint: What can you say about the derivative of $f^2 + g^2$?

Comment: you should write $(fg)^\prime$ instead of $fg^\prime$ when you really mean the former.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you! That was a careless typo. Will make that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense, but I don't see how the prove what you want to prove starting like that.

Note that$$(f^2+g^2)'=2ff'+2gg'=2(fg-gf)=0.$$Therefore, $f^2+g^2$ is constant. But $f^2(0)+g^2(0)=1$, and so $f^2+g^2=1$.

Comment: Correct, of course, but I'd rather you'd waited to give the OP a chance to discover this himself starting with a hint.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, you're right. That's what I should have done.

Comment: thank you! Both of you! @EthanBolker I actually saw your hint before I saw his answer and from it was able to come up with the answer. But how did both of you know to start from there? I'm new to this and feel like I'm never starting any proof right.

Comment: @StatBegnr Whenever you'r trying to prove that a differentiable function $f$ is constant, the first thing to do is to see if $f'=0$.

Comment: @StatBegnr Well we both knew because it's a standard exercise. The general principle is that if you're asked to prove something is constant, looking at its derivative is often a good place to start. And we both made that comment here essentially simultaneously.